# Create AssetCategory with AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil

Tags: nullpointerexception, liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to create [AssetCategory](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/asset/model/AssetCategory.html) using the method [addCategory](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/asset/service/AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.html#addCategory%28long,%20long,%20java.util.Map,%20java.util.Map,%20long,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext%29) of [AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/asset/service/AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.html#addCategory%28long,%20long,%20java.util.Map,%20long,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext%29). However, I am not aware of what I should specify as ServiceContext. Unlike the other add-methods of LocalServiceUtil classes (Group, Organizations), I deduce that I cannot set the ServiceContext to null. I have tried and I receive a NullPointerExeption when calling the method. If I try to create one, just to pass it in the method, I receive an AssetCategoryNameException. I create it as:

```java
ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(180);
```

How can I come over the above problem (create the AssetCategory without exception)?

**UPDATE:** I need also to specify a vocabularyId. How can I get a Vocabulary (or a list of Vocabularies) to be able to get its id? I tried the code:

```java
List<AssetVocabulary> vl = AssetVocabularyUtil.findAll();.
int VocabId = vl.get(0).getVocabularyId();
```

but it throws the exception:
 org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here

What could I do to get the VocabularyId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code out, I hope it can help you:

```java
// you can particularise your serviceContext as @Jonas Fonseca says
ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
Map<Locale,String> titleMap = new HashMap<Locale, String>();
titleMap.put(Locale.getDefault(), "categoryName");
// vocabularyID needs to point to an existing vocabulary
AssetCategoryLocalServiceUtil.addCategory(userId, parentCategoryId, titleMap, new HashMap<Locale,String>(), vocabularyID, new String[]{}, serviceContext);
```

Of course is the simplest example about how to create an `AssetCategory`, but it works fine.

**UPDATE:**

If you need the vocabulary you can something like:

```java
// in case you have vocabulary id
AssetVocabularyLocalServiceUtil.getVocabulary(vocabularyId);
// in case you have the vocabulary name
AssetVocabularyLocalServiceUtil.getGroupVocabulary(groupId, vocabularyName);
// you can get all vocabularies in group
AssetVocabularyLocalServiceUtil.getGroupVocabularies(groupId);
// ...or all vocabularies in portal
int count = AssetVocabularyLocalServiceUtil.getAssetVocabulariesCount();
AssetVocabularyLocalServiceUtil.getAssetVocabularies(0, count);
```

(Remember to call *LocalServiceUtil methods instead *Util so you can avoid the Hibernate exception)

Comment: I have solved the problem of the AssetCategoryNameException, after I changed the Locale to Locale.US. My problem is now how I can get the vocabularyId, because now it throws a NoSuchVocabularyException.

Comment: If you have already created the `AssetVocabulary`, you can get it with `AssetVocabularyLocalServiceUtil.getGroupVocabulary(groupId,vocabularyName)`. Of course, if you have the vocabulary id, you just need to pass it to `addCategory` method.

Comment: What I need actually is the vocabularyId to pass it in the method addCategory. I have created a Vocabulary but I do not know how can I get its id in the code. That is my question.

Comment: Check my update, please. It will work for you if you have either vocabularyId or vocabularyName.

Comment: I have looked at it, but I have neither the groupId nor the vocabularyName. What can be done in that case?

Comment: I don't get it, you must have anything to identify the vocabulary... of course, you always can get all vocabularies in a group or in the whole portal. I'll update again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `AssetCategoryNameException`it means that the name is [invalid](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/asset/service/impl/AssetCategoryLocalServiceImpl.java#L537), for example null.

What information you need to set in `ServiceContext`depends on the service you call. As a minimum you should set the userId (which will be set as the owner), the groupId of the site and the companyId. In addition, should also set the permission properties, which control who can view asset category, especially if the category will be used in conjunction with the asset publisher, which can filter content based on view permissions.

```java
ServiceContext createServiceContext(ThemeDisplay themeDisplay) {
    ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
    serviceContext.setCompanyId(themeDisplay.getCompanyId());
    serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(themeDisplay.getScopeGroupId());
    serviceContext.setUserId(themeDisplay.getUserId());
    serviceContext.setAddCommunityPermissions(true);
    serviceContext.setAddGuestPermissions(true);
    return serviceContext;
}
```

Comment: How can I set the name (of the category) in order not to be null?

Comment: This error indicates that you are passing a name that is null, however, I would have to see the code in order to answer this question.

Comment: I use the method addCategory. You can click the link on my original question to see that it takes no parameter name.

Comment: The name is taken from the titleMap argument. Make sure that it at least contains a title for the default locale of the portal.